# Ansible loops and conditionals

Tags: loops, ansible, conditional-statements

Ansible docs states that:

> Combining when with with_items (see [Loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html)), be aware that the when statement is processed separately for each item.

However when I try to skip one item in task, it doesn't work that way:

```
value_var: [1, 5]

- name: register variable
  command: echo "4"
  register: var

- name: conditional check
  command: nevermind
  when: var.stdout > item
```

By my understanding, that I would get `changed` on first item within `conditional check` task, and `skipped` on second item. But I get:

```
changed: [guest] => (item=5)
changed: [guest] => (item=1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with loops. You are comparing a string (the result of `echo` command) with an integer.

You should first cast the value:

```
when: var.stdout|int > item
```